# Gershgorin-type bounds for smallest eigenvalue of positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, lower-bounds

I would like to know if there are known results for bounding eigenvalues of positive-definite matrices, in particular gram matrices $AA^\top$ based on easily computable functions of $A$.

Gershgorin bounds are too loose for the smallest eigenvalue of a gram matrix, typically giving negative bounds, which are of course vacuous for a gram matrix.

Comment: if computing characteristic polynomial of $AA^\top$ counts as easy, you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Polynomials_whose_roots_are_all_real